# Create transparent HTML table

Tags: css, html

I would like to create HTML table like this example.

[image]

How I can preserve the header gray and make the data to look like the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working snippet.

1. border-spacing removes the spacing between cells
2. tr:first-of-type targets only the first row to apply background color
3. td:nth-child(odd) targets only the first column to make all fields bold

```css
table{
  border-spacing:0;
}

tr:first-of-type{
  background:lightgray;
  }

td:nth-child(odd){
  font-weight:bold;
}

th,td{
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Plan / Feature</td>
    <td>Standard</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Plan Type</td>
    <td>Annual</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email Support</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`CSS:`

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table th, table thead tr {
    background: #ccc;
    font-weight: bold;
}

table tr td:first-child {
    font-weight: bold;
}

table tr td {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

`Example HTML:`

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x7hd763x/)

Answer (score 1):

You can style the header of a table with css

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
    </tr>
</table>

th { background-color: #ff0000; }
```

Or see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h4817knp/6/

Edit: To avoid the gaps in the header add

```
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
```

to the css

http://jsfiddle.net/1yn99g13/1/

Comment: That has gaps between the header cells which aren't in the question.

Comment: That code is syntactically incorrect

Comment: what exactly is syntactically incorrect?

Comment: All `td` and `th` elements should be placed inside a `<tr></tr>` http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: I have removed my downvote `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You just set the background colour on the elements you want it to appear on.

There's nothing complicated about this.

```
table, tbody, tr, th, td { background: transparent; }
thead { background: #aaa; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should, of course, use CSS:

You need to get rid of the default spacing in the table:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

You need to set the background color of the table head element:

```
table thead {
    background-color: lightgrey;  
}
```

You need to define your cell sizes:

```
td {
    width: 100px;  
    height: 25px;
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonwilczak/tmo7u3fa/)

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}
td {
    width: 100px;  
    height: 25px;
}
table thead {
    background-color: lightgrey;  
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>HeaderA</td>
            <td>HeaderB</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>Value</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```